# excel: index match where date is within 1 week?

Tags: excel, indexing

```
I have an excel spreadsheet with some rows of data on sheet1 like so:

Sheet1:

    ID       Subject          Date
    1        Tennis           23/04/2016
    2        Football         19/05/2016
    3        Golf             22/04/2016
```

Then on sheet2 i want to create a list of activities happening within 1 week:

Sheet2:

```
Activities 1 week away

Golf
Tennis
```

So because both golf and tennis are happening 22nd and 23rd of April and are both within 1 week away from today, these should be displayed in date descending order.

To do this, i know i need to create an index match and set parameters for my dates to see if these are within 7 days. However i cannot get the below to work:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$G:$G,MIN(IF(Data!$E$2:$E$5000>=TODAY()-7),ROW($2:$5000)),1,"")
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you are open to VBA:

```
'AMENDED with the assumption that the ID field is unique
Sub UpcomingAgenda()

Dim agendaRange As Range
Dim Dictionary As Object
Set Dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Item In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C6")
    If Item.Value >= Date And Item.Value < Date + 7 Then
        Dictionary.Add Item.Offset(0, -2).Value, Item.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
Next

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)) = ""
    Set agendaRange = .Range("A1").Resize(Dictionary.Count, 1)
    agendaRange = Application.Transpose(Dictionary.items)
End With

Set Dictionary = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is my new code that solves the duplicate problem above (without sorting). My apologies! There's probably a better way but I'm still learning myself. I hope it helps in some way. :-)

```
Sub UpcomingAgenda()

Dim agendaRange As Range
Dim agenda() As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For Each Item In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C5")
    If Item.Value < Date + 7 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next

i = 0
ReDim agenda(counter - 1)
For Each Item In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C5")
    If Item.Value < Date + 7 Then
        agenda(i) = Item.Offset(0, -1).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)) = ""
    Set agendaRange = .Range("A1").Resize(counter, 1)
    agendaRange = Application.Transpose(agenda)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't use Dictionary much, but does Dictionary allow for duplicates?  If Golf happens to happen twice in the week will this throw an error?  I can't remember.

Comment: I don't think so. Each item is keyed differently. @ScottCraner Edit: doh, should read code first. Yea, Brain is keying with subject so duplicate would be bad.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Nice catch Scott!! Thanks for that.

Comment: @Brian thanks for this suggestion, seems to work great!

Comment: Another observation the OP wanted these in order by date also.  I like your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIF (even if its not in formulas) :

```
IF((DATEDIF(TODAY(),C10,"D"))<7,"yes","no")
```

Where C10 is your date field.

Answer (score 0):

The INDEX/MATCH will only return the first match.

You need to combine the INDEX with the Aggregate function to get the order desired.

The best way, so as to deal with duplicate dates is to add a second column on Sheet2 with the dates.  So in B2 on Sheet 2 put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,Sheet1!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$C:$C))/((Sheet1!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$C:$C))<=TODAY()+7)*(Sheet1!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$C:$C))>TODAY()-1)),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then we reference B2 in A2 with this formula:

```
=IF(B2<>"",INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$C:$C)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$C:$C)))-1)/(Sheet1!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$C:$C))=B2),COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2))),"")
```

Then drag down as needed to capture all the desired events.

This is a non CSE array formula.  Array formulas calculations are exponential, so we need to limit the reference range to the minimum needed.  All the `INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet1!$C:$C))` find the last cell with data and sets this as the end reference.

The `IFERROR()` wrapper on the first allows the formula to be copied down further than the list will return and avoid the `#N/A`.  In the picture the formulas occupy the first 8 rows.

[image]

---

Sheet1 for reference:

[image]